# show that language is regular

Tags: automata, regular-language

Let $B_n = \{a^k\ |\text{ where } k\text{ is a multiple of } n\}$. Show
that for each $n\ge 1$ the $B_n$ language is regular.

My proposition of solution:
[image]

What about it ?

Comment: This solution is perfectly fine. Well done!

Comment: There was easier way:
$B_n=(a^n)^*$

Comment: This all depends on what you know about the condition of being "regular". If you don't know of regular expressions or any other criterion, you have to provide an automaton. But there are plenty of equivalent definitions for regularity. You could even try to prove the regularity of this language with each of them in order to be sure that you master all of them!